# Specify unique levels when creating multiple factors

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a dataframe which I am trying to turn into factors. I want each row to represent a factor, with the levels ordered in the order that the values appear. My code is falling short of this last task:

```
> x
   V11 V12 V13 V21 V22 V23 V31 V32 V33 V41 V42 V43
r1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
r2   1   2   3   4   5   6  10  11  12   7   8   9
r3   1   2   3   7   8   9  10  11  12   4   5   6
r4   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12   1   2   3
> 
> x %>%
+   t %>%
+   as_data_frame %>%
+   mutate_all(factor) %>%
+   lapply(., unlist)
$r1
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

$r2
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  10 11 12 7  8  9 
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

$r3
 [1] 1  2  3  7  8  9  10 11 12 4  5  6 
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

$r4
 [1] 4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 1  2  3 
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Is there any way to specify that the levels should match the other of each column in the initial dataframe (it was transformed as the first piped command); right now each factor has the same order of levels which is incorrect.

Comment: You can use `x %>% t %>% as.data.frame() %>% mutate_all(funs(factor(., levels = unique(.)))) %>% lapply(., unlist)`

Comment: @akrun, that's perfect; I realise I almost answered my own question in the title now!

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the `levels =` argument  inside `factor()`:

```
lapply(data.frame(t(df)), function(x) factor(x, levels = unique(x)))
#$r1
# [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12
#Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

#$r2
# [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  10 11 12 7  8  9 
#Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 7 8 9

#$r3
# [1] 1  2  3  7  8  9  10 11 12 4  5  6 
#Levels: 1 2 3 7 8 9 10 11 12 4 5 6

#$r4
# [1] 4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 1  2  3 
#Levels: 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1 2 3
```

Comment: You can also include the `tidyverse` i.e. `x %>% 
  t %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(factor(., levels = unique(.)))) %>% 
  lapply(., unlist)`

Comment: I got burnt with this approach as it fails on dates : `x <- Sys.Date();factor(x,unique(x))` will return `NA` with the correct level, to avoid this use `factor(x, as.character(unique(x)))`, it will not change the behavior for character / numeric/logical ...